# Creating a series of show/hide screens in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been tasked with implementing a series of tutorial screens. The user either moves from one to the next, or opts out, in which case the tutorial itself goes away.

There is an outer div that contains each 'step' -- Step 1, step 2, step 3, etc.  If the user clicks the 'Continue' button then the subsequent step is shown. Here is the first step (numbered 0):

```
<div class="outerdiv" ng-show=isTutorialVisible>
   <div class="step step--0" ng-show="go-to-step == 0">
     <div class="row-fluid">
           <h2 class="welcome__head">Welcome to Our Store</h2>
                 <div class="welcome__buttons">
                    <a href="" class="button">No, thanks</a>
                    <a href=""  class="button--primary"
                              ng-click="moveToNextScreen(1);">Continue</a>
                       </div>
                  </div> 
         <div class="span3">
            <button type="button" class="close-button" ng-click="close();">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So clicking the 'Continue' button should take the user to the next step.

I have in the controller:

```
 $scope.goToStep = 0;    //or should this just be var goToStep?
 $scope.moveToNextScreen = function (screenNumber){
  goToStep = screenNumber;
 }
```

But when the page runs, if I enter any of the variables on the scope, such as goToStep, in the console, it shows an undefined ReferenceError.  Why is that?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this:

`goToStep = screenNumber;`

`goToStep` is not defined.  You should use:

`$scope.goToStep = screenNumber;`